# How can I make it so a button is only enabled once a button before it has been pressed?

Tags: uibutton, storyboard

I'm making an app that when a button is pressed an animation or video plays, then the user is supposed to press the next button in the series to get the next movie or animation to play. This tells a story and as such I need them to play in a certain order.

So I need a way to make a button disabled until the button before it is pressed.

I need to do this for a total of five buttons.

I am working with storyboard in Xcode 5.

Please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write following line at the end of the IBAction method of every button

```
[sender setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks! Using this in clever ways has gotten me the exact functionality I need. Do you know how I can make make it so once a button is pressed it is disabled for a set amount of time? Or until my animation has finished playing?

Comment: you can do this by following code `[UIView animateWithDuration:10.0
                     animations:^{
                         [sender setHidden:YES];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [sender setHidden:NO];
                     }];`